How to route the audio during off-hook call state towards main speaker instead of earpiece speaker in Kotlin
I'm working on an Android application where I need to play a sound through the loudspeaker when our device is in an off-hook or connected call state, as currently the sound is getting played through the earpiece speaker. I'm using the MediaPlayer class and attempting to route the audio to the loudspeaker using the AudioManager. Below is the code I've written, but I'm encountering issues and would like to understand how to improve or fix it.
private fun playSound() {
    try {
        val audioManager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        
        // Attempt to route the audio to the loudspeaker
        try {
            audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION // Try to set the mode
            audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn = true // Try to route to loudspeaker
            Log.d("PhoneCallForegroundService", "Speakerphone set to ON")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("PhoneCallForegroundService", "Error setting speakerphone on", e)
        }

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
        val afd = resources.openRawResourceFd(R.raw.gacha)
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.fileDescriptor, afd.startOffset, afd.length)
        afd.close()

        mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(
            AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                .build()
        )

        mediaPlayer.prepare()
        mediaPlayer.start()
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener {
            Log.d("PhoneCallForegroundService", "Sound playback completed")
            it.release()

      /*      // Optionally reset the speakerphone setting
            try {
                audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn = false
                audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL
                Log.d("PhoneCallForegroundService", "Speakerphone set to OFF, mode set to NORMAL")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("PhoneCallForegroundService", "Error resetting speakerphone or mode", e)
            } */
        } 

        Log.d("PhoneCallForegroundService", "Sound playback started")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("PhoneCallForegroundService", "Error during sound playback", e)
    }
}

Questions:
Is the approach to routing audio to the loudspeaker correct?
Are there any recommended improvements or best practices for handling audio playback and exceptions in this scenario?
Is there a more effective way to reset the speakerphone and audio mode after playback?

Try by removing all the code related to audioManager. The mediaPlayer is supposed to play on speaker by default.

@dev.tejasb I am trying to play my audio through the loudspeaker when our Android device is in an off-hook or connected call state.

You added this after I commented! Anyways, I'll write here if I find a solutions.
